# How to add data from array of object with array inside to another array of object? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

This is my code, I want to create another filtered array like the example below, I have 2 arrays and want to add score information to it, I know it's simple but can't find the solution

```
  const wishesData = [
    {
       name: "Peter",
      presents: ["coffee", "holidays"]
    },
    {
       name: "Mario",
      presents: ["coffee", "videogames"]
    },
    {
       name: "Amanda",
      presents: ["computer", "tattoo"]
    }
  ]
  const scoresData= [
    {
      name: "Peter",
      score: 10
    },
    {
      name: "Mario",
      score: 2.3
    },
    {
       name: "Amanda",
      score: 1.1
    }
  ]
  const result = wishesData.map((ele) => {
      return {
               ...ele,
              score:  scoresData.find(s=> s.name === ele.name? s.score: 0)
                  }
  })
           console.log("este es el resultado=>",result)
```

I want to modify the array wishesData adding "score" to all objects inside and get to look like this example:

```
{
  name: "Mario",
  presents: ["coffee", "videogames"],
  score: 2.3
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the example and correction and suggestions.

- Correction: `scoresData.find(s=> s.name === ele.name? s.score: 0)` - here you do not close bracket for `Array.find` and try to access it's property within `find`. In your code, you will get `scoreData` object instead of `score`.

```js
const match = scoresData.find(s=> s.name === ele.name); // -> ? s.score: 0)
return match ? match.score : 0;

// or simply
const score = scoresData.find(s=> s.name === ele.name)?.score || 0;
```

- Suggestion: it will take O(N^2) time. All iteration for `wishesData` need another iteration `scoresData` for each. Why don't you use `reduce` provided in example?

```js
const scoreMap = scoresData.reduce((a, c) => ({
    ...a,
    [c.name]: c.score
}), {})

// you can easy to find score by
const result = wishesData.map((ele) => {
    return {
        ...ele,
        score: scoreMap[ele.name] || 0,
    }
})
```

Thanks

```js
const wishesData = [{
        name: "Peter",
        presents: ["coffee", "holidays"]
    },
    {
        name: "Mario",
        presents: ["coffee", "videogames"]
    },
    {
        name: "Amanda",
        presents: ["computer", "tattoo"]
    }
]
const scoresData = [{
        name: "Peter",
        score: 10
    },
    {
        name: "Mario",
        score: 2.3
    },
    {
        name: "Amanda",
        score: 1.1
    }
]
const scoreMap = scoresData.reduce((a, c) => ({
    ...a,
    [c.name]: c.score
}), {})
const result = wishesData.map((ele) => {
    return {
        ...ele,
        score: scoreMap[ele.name] || 0,
    }
})
console.log("este es el resultado=>", result)
```

And this is just editing of your origin code

```js
const wishesData = [{
        name: "Peter",
        presents: ["coffee", "holidays"]
    },
    {
        name: "Mario",
        presents: ["coffee", "videogames"]
    },
    {
        name: "Amanda",
        presents: ["computer", "tattoo"]
    }
]
const scoresData = [{
        name: "Peter",
        score: 10
    },
    {
        name: "Mario",
        score: 2.3
    },
    {
        name: "Amanda",
        score: 1.1
    }
]
const result = wishesData.map((ele) => {
    return {
        ...ele,
        score: scoresData.find(s => s.name === ele.name)?.score || 0
    }
})
console.log("este es el resultado=>", result)
```

Comment: Good explanation!

Comment: Thanks @AnuragSrivastava

Answer (score 1):

You return the whole object, just return the score:

```js
const wishesData = [{
    name: "Peter",
    presents: ["coffee", "holidays"]
  },
  {
    name: "Mario",
    presents: ["coffee", "videogames"]
  },
  {
    name: "Amanda",
    presents: ["computer", "tattoo"]
  },
  {
    name: "Another",
    presents: ["computer", "tattoo"]
  }
]
const scoresData = [{
    name: "Peter",
    score: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Mario",
    score: 2.3
  },
  {
    name: "Amanda",
    score: 1.1
  }
]
const result = wishesData.map(ele => {
  const match = scoresData.find(s => s.name === ele.name)  
  return { ...ele, score: match ? match.score : 0  }
})
console.log("este es el resultado=>", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const wishesWithScores = wishesData.map(wishObject => {
  const descriptor = wishObject.name;
  const { score } = scoresData.find(({ name }) => name === descriptor);

  return {
    ...wishObject,
    score
  }
});
```

Comment: A small explanation of what this does would be helpful

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28025566)